# Reverse a chown command

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, command-line

**What I did**

Last night while updating plugins on my Wordpress site my site crashed and I had to spin up a new server and restore from a Vaultpress backup. Once the restore had finished propogating I was unable to update the plugins so I ran the command

`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/`

I got the response

`-bash: cd: /var/www/html: No such file or director`

So after a bit of snooping I determined my directory path was off slightly. So, I ran

`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/html.old`

**What happened**

After running the `chown` command when I attempt to install plugin updates I get this in-browser error message:

---

**Not Found**

The requested URL /wp-admin/plugins.php was not found on this server.

*Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at $domain Port 80*

---

**My question**

Obviously I broke something when I ran the `chown` command, so how do I undo the command that I ran?

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Just restore the backup again?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but I am hoping to avoid that option as it will take an hour plus and in the end I will still be in the same predicament of not being able to install plugin/wordpress updates....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to revert the chown command unless you have a backup or know which file belongs to whom or all files belonged to a single user, which I doubt is the case here.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying Ajit. For anyone else having similar issues, my server and all its consequent backups were running an old version of PHP. When I tried to install the backups on a new server the dichotomy between PHP versions was  causing my server to issue a slew of ominous error messages. Lesson learned, stay on top of server updates :(